# perl: Is there a heuristic for finding mismatched braces/brackets/parens etc

Tags: perl, heuristics

I'm using perl to parse a json file. When all is OK, I find matching braces fine. But if there is a mismatch, I can't think of a good way of finding where it is.

My data at this point is a sorted array (@merged)
 of offsets of braces in the file, with offsets of closing braces set negative.

Here's the section that does the matching:

```
    @stack=();
    foreach $val (@merged) # go through merged array
    {   if ($val>0) { push @stack, $val;} # push every opener onto a stack
        else {  $opn = pop @stack; # when a closer comes up, pop previous opener
                @tmp = ($opn, abs $val); # array of one match
                push @matches, [@tmp];  # the array of all matches
            }
    }
```

I also have information about the column, but I don't want the algorithm to depend on compulsive formatting.

I'd like to adapt this to perl text as well, for those times when the translator just says there's an unmatched brace at the end.

Are there any good heuristics for finding the location of the mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

Use a parser, do not try to reinvent the wheel.  Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw( decode_json encode_json );

my $data = { foo => 'bar', baz => [1,2,3], qux => { abc => 1, def => 2, ghi => 3} };
my $json = encode_json($data);

my $error_json = $json;
$error_json =~ s|\]||; # Remove a closing square bracket

eval {
    my $error_data = decode_json($error_json); # Will throw an error
};
my $error = $@;
if ($error) {
    print "JSON Error : $error";
    my ($char_pos) = $error =~ m|at character offset (\d+)|;
    print "Original   : '$json'\n";
    print "Error      : '$error_json'\n";
    print "..............";
    print "."x($char_pos) . "^\n";

} else {
    die "should not get here...something went wrong";
}
```

**Output**

```
JSON Error : , or ] expected while parsing array, at character offset 31 (before ":{"abc":1,"ghi":3,"d...") at foo.pl line 15.
Original   : '{"foo":"bar","baz":[1,2,3],"qux":{"abc":1,"ghi":3,"def":2}}'
Error      : '{"foo":"bar","baz":[1,2,3,"qux":{"abc":1,"ghi":3,"def":2}}'
.............................................^
```

Comment: Part of the reason I program is to get something done, and part of the reason is to learn to program. Using a black box doesn't serve that latter function. Besides, when I DO use a black box, say a perl interpreter, it never tells me Where the bracket is missing. It usually just points at the last bracket in the file, and leaves it to me to laboriously manually check all the brackets. That's why I'm trying to see if there's some heuristic that can narrow it down to where I should look for the error. It's easier in XML, since the close "brackets" explicitly say what they're closing.

Comment: Well, you can look at the source of the JSON parser here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm.  In general, writing a parser is non-trivial and you will basically need to write one to do what you want to do.

Comment: If you are having trouble writing new perl code, and don't like what the perl -c is telling you (because it can be unclear what the issue is..), the general strategy is to start with a compiling program and as you add more code, you check that it still compiles.  If you have an existing program, you can try commenting out sections until it compiles, then slowly uncommenting lines of code to find the _real_ issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found an heuristic which works much of the time, especially if you're compulsive about lining up opening and closing brackets.

I scan the file, find matching brackets, and find the difference between the columns. The error usually stands out as a larger difference than most of the matches.

Of course, I have to ignore brackets in comments or in quotes.

I have used this with .pl and .js files, and it works well.